# Javascript (Regex): How do i replace (Backslash + Double Quote) pairs?

Tags: javascript, regex, double-quotes, backslash

In Javascript, i want the below original string:

> I want to replace \"this\" and \"that\" words, but NOT the one "here"

.. to become like:

> I want to replace ^this^ and ^that^ words, but NOT the one "here"

I tried something like:

```
var str = 'I want to replace \"this\" and \"that\" words, but NOT the one "here"';
str = str.replace(/\"/g,"^");
console.log( str );
```

Demo: [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/amy8xx80/).

**But still** .. the output is:

> I want to replace ^this^ and ^that^ words, but NOT the one ^here^

Which means i wanted to replace only the `\"` occurrences but NOT the `"` alone. But i cannot.

Please help.

Comment: The line of code that starts `var str = ` creates a string with zero backslashes in it. In a string literal, if you want the resulting string to contain a backslash you have to escape it: `var str = 'I ... \\"this\\" and...'`. You would also have to escape the backslash in your regex.

Comment: ^ and there's that, escape characters in a string literal are treated as ... escape characters -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ddst9ok2/

Comment: Yes so.. how do i achieve this in JS please?

Comment: You don't, there are no backslashes to replace

Comment: Urrrg.. JS sucks then.

Comment: But why are you doing this, do you really have a string literal like that?

Comment: Yes i do have these.

Comment: You need to clarify: are you giving the string in "raw" form, or in JS literal string format? In other words, do the backslashes actually exist as literal characters in the string, as would be the case if it were written in code as `String.raw\`I want to replace \"this\"\``, or coming from a server with the backslashes actually there? Or are those backslashes inside a JS string literal which are escaping the `"` into itself? I suspect the former, but please confirm.

Answer (score 2):

As @adeneo's comment, your string was created wrong and not exactly like your expectation. Please try this:

```
var str = 'I want to replace \\"this\\" and \\"that\\" words, but not the one "here"';
str = str.replace(/\\\"/g,"^");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the `"` in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` `/(")/`, `String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`, `String.prototype.slice()` to check if matched character is last or second to last match in input string. If true, return original match, else replace match with `"^"` character.

```js
var str = `I want to replace \"this\" and \"that\" words, but NOT the one "here"`;

var res = str.replace(/(")/g, function(match, _, index) {
  return index === str.lastIndexOf(match) 
         || index === str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf(match) -1)
                      .lastIndexOf(match)
         ? match
         : "^"
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: You are not expressing the string given by the OP correctly. To reproduce it as a string literal in JS, you would have needed to write `\\"`.

Comment: this solution is over complex! This can be achieved easier.

Comment: This assumes that the ones not to match will always be at the end of the string, and ignores the OP's requirement to match on a backslash followed by a double-quote (even though the OP is confused about what that means).

Comment: @torazaburo Used string at OP. Did not review Question enough. Though, note, OP has not adjusted string at original Question.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, you are correct. used string at OP. Though should have read Question more thoroughly. Actually just looked at string, determined which was different, and attempted to match those characters. Not certain about OP's actual string is? String at original Question has not been edited or updated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with String.prototype.replace is that it only replaces the first occurrence without Regular Expression.  To fix this, you need to add a `g` and the end of the RegEx, like so:

```
var mod = str => str.replace(/\\\"/g,'^');
mod('I want to replace \\"this\\" and \\"that\\" words, but NOT the one "here"');
```

A less effective but easier to understand to do what you wanted is to split the string with the delimiter and then join it with the replacement, like so:

```
var mod = str => str.split('\\"').join('^');
mod('I want to replace \\"this\\" and \\"that\\" words, but NOT the one "here"');
```

Note: You can wrap a string with either ' or ".  Suppose your string contains ", i.e. a"a, you will need to put an \ in front of the " as `"a"a"` causes syntax error.  `'a"a'` won't cause syntax error as the parser knows the " is part of the string, but when you put a \ in front of " or any other special characters, it means the following character is a special character.  So `'a\"a'` === `'a"a'` === `"a\"a"`.  If you want to store \, you will need to use \ regardless of the type of quote you use, so to store \", you will need to use `'\\"'`, `'\\\"'` or `"\\\""`.

Comment: What is the difference inside the regexp between `\"` and `"`, without escaping it?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.